# Tensorflow pretrained model import error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on an object detection model in tensorflow. I have a file `model.py`:

```
from PIL import Image   
import cv2   
import numpy as np   
import tensorflow as tf   
from .squeezenet import SqueezeNet

save_path = "sqnet/squeezenet.ckpt"
sess = tf.Session()
model = SqueezeNet(save_path=save_path, sess=sess)

class Finder(object):
    def __init__(self, image_path):
        self.image_path = image_path

    def predict(self):
        image = process(self.image_path)
        ans = sess.run(model.classifier, feed_dict={model.image: 
                       image})
        return ans


def process(path):
    image = Image.open(path)
    # image.show()
    image = np.array(image)
    image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(224, 224), 
                       interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    image = image.reshape((1, 224, 224, 3))
    #print(image.shape)
    #img = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
    return image


image_path = "/home/jatin/ai.jpeg"

object_detector = Finder(image_path)

ans = object_detector.predict()

print(np.argmax(ans))

sess.close()
```

I have a folder named `sqnet` alongside the `model.py` file within which I have `squuezenet.cpkt` file. But running this gives the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful
>   TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on
>   sqnet/squeezenet.ckpt: Not found: sqnet; No such file or directory.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Seems like a simple IO error to me. Have you tried using absolute path `save_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'sqnet', 'squeezenet.ckpt')`? No one can be sure since it is not reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much @YohanesGultom. It worked, but still why it didn't accept relative path?

Comment: well it very much depends on the implementation inside `SqueezeNet` itself. Btw, I will also put the solution as an answer. Please accept it so other can also learn from this case

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple IO error to me. Have you tried using absolute path?

```
save_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'sqnet', 'squeezenet.ckpt')
```